# Translating binary plaintext into alphabetic plaintext using an $18$-digit base-$26$ integer system

Tags: cryptography, decimal-expansion

I'm working on a cryptography problem and went through the long process of decrypting a sent message to get a $27$ digit number.

It then says: Plaintext blocks have $18$ letters and that such an alphabetic block is converted to a decimal string by considering it to be an $18$-digit base-$26$ integer (where $A$ represents $0$, $B$ represents $1$, etc.) and then taking the decimal expansion of this integer. I really have no idea of what this means or how to begin, can someone please just point me in the right direction.

For example, how would the alphabetic plaintext "HELLO" be made into a plaintext message.

Answer (score 2):

In general a base-$n$ number has a value given by the summation of the digits multiplied by $n^k$ where $k$ is their position in the number starting at $0$.

For example, the number $234=2*10^2+3*10^1+4*10^0$ in base-$10$. In base $26$ the number represented by "HELLO" given in your example would be $7|4|11|11|14=7*26^4+4*26^3+11*26^2+11*26^1+15*26^0=3276873$.

Comment: so the number I have from decrypting is $p_{1}*26^17+p_{2}*26^16+...+p_{18}*26^0$? Is that I should go about trying to solve this for an alphabetic message?

Comment: Yes that seems correct from your description. If you gave the actual plaintext I could help further.

Comment: how would you solve that though considering its one equation with 18 unknowns?

Comment: Well its quite easy to convert between different bases by using an online tool.

Comment: I'm trying to get the letters though what other base would I be converting too?

Comment: Base 26 because each plaintext can be written as a base 26 integer.

Comment: You don't have to solve anything when you receive a number and want to go back: Suppose you receive $x$ as an integer. Now compute its base 26 representation; ook at the first $n$ such that $26^n > x$, that's the number of "letter-digits" (you expect 18 of them I believe). Then $26^{n-1} \le x$ and the quotient modulo $26^{n-1}$ is the highest "letter digit" and you continue this process with the remainder.. It's the same algorithm as when you convert to binary or octal or hexadecimal, but with a differnent base. Look it up.